# $("myDropDown option[value*='? object']") what exact this mean, in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I came to face below code in my project in Jquery. 
But didn't get meaning of that line.

```
if($("#myDropDown option[value*='? object']").length>0 ||
$("#myDropDown option[value*='? number']").length>0 ||
$("#myDropDown option[value*='? string']").length>0)
{
 $("#myDropDown").find('option:first').remove();
}
```

Can any one explain what does it mean. I know that if condition match, it will remove first option from dropdown. but what is exact meaning of condition? 
Is it searching for type of value in option? which I believe always string, then why it required object and number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an attribute contains selector ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) | [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)).

The selector `#myDropDown option[value*='? object']` means: "find all `option` elements whose `value` attribute contains `? object` anywhere in their value that are descendants of the element with the ID `myDropDown`."